# Attribute Error When Clicking Model in Admin Section of Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, attributeerror

I'm using Django and I'm getting the error AttributeError at /admin/network/post/
'Post' object has no attribute 'user'

The strange thing is this error happens when I'm looking at the admin section, and clicking 'Posts.' I only have models for users and posts. Not sure how to fix this error because so far I've never gotten an error like this when clicking it in the admin section of the site: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

I think the issue is in my model because the view for creating a post works totally fine.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='author', 
    null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)      
    like = models.ManyToManyField(
    User,  blank=True, related_name="liked_user")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Follow(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='followers')
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='targets')
```

views.py

```
def make_post(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form_for_post = {'form': PostForm()}
        return render(request, "network/make_post.html", form_for_post)
    else:

        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            new_post = Post.objects.create(
            text=text,
            username=request.user,
            )
        return render(request, "network/make_post.html", {
            "new_post": new_post,
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined the field that refs to a `User` in the `Post` model to be `username`, not <s>user</s>, although `user` should be a *better* idea.

You thus should implement the `__str__` method as:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # …
    username = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author', null=True, blank=True)
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username.username
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).